# Append string after nth occurrence of a string

Tags: java

I have a string `s` to which I want to append another string `s1` at the specified position.

```
String s = "17.4755,2.0585,23.6489,12.0045";
String s1=",,,,"
```

Now I want to add the string `s1` after the n-th occurrence of `","` character.

I have just started learning Java.

Comment: Put what expected output?

Comment: nth occurenece of `. (dot)`? share the output u want

Comment: so what is stopping you? you have started learning Java, so you should be able to start attempting to solve this

Comment: What should happen if `s1` should be added after the 7th occurrence of `,` (comma)?

Comment: Please explain what you tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```
public String insert(int n, String original, String other) {
    int index = original.indexOf(',');
    while(--n > 0 && index != -1) {
        index = original.indexOf(',', index + 1);
    }
    if(index == -1) {
        return original;
    } else {
        return original.substring(0, index) + other + original.substring(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - just add a condition for addition to the start of the String. and i will accept your answer

Comment: what do you mean by *condition for addition*?

Comment: Your code is not working it i try to add a string at the start or at the end of the original String.

Comment: public class TestClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String x=",,,,17.4755,2.0585,23.6489,12.0045";
  String s=new TestClass().insert(8, x, ",,,,");
  System.out.println(s);
 }
 
 public String insert(int n, String original, String other) {
     int index = original.indexOf(',');
     while(--n > 0 && index != -1) {
         index = original.indexOf(',', index + 1);
     }
     if(index == -1) {
         return original;
     } else {
         return original.substring(0, index) + other + original.substring(index);
     }
 }
}

Comment: @user9880920 Of course it doesn't. Because you're trying to insert your `",,,,"` string *after* the 8th occurance of comma (`,`). But the `String` you provided only contains 7 commans

Answer (score 0):

Working with `String`s directly is not worth the trouble.

One easy way would be to turn your `String` into a `List` and manipulate that.

```
public void test() {
    String s = "17.4755,2.0585,23.6489,12.0045";
    // Split s into parts.
    String[] parts = s.split(",");
    // Convert it to a list so we can insert.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(parts));
    // Inset 3 blank fields at position 2.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        list.add(2,"");
    }
    // Create my new string.
    String changed = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    System.out.println(changed);
}
```

Prints:

> 17.4755,2.0585,,,,23.6489,12.0045

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is what you want**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s = "17.4755,2.0585,23.6489,12.0045";

    String s1=",,,,";

    System.out.println("Enter Nth Occurrence");
    try {
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        long totalOccurrence = 0;

        if (n != 0) {

            totalOccurrence = s.chars().filter(num -> num == ',').count();

            if (totalOccurrence < n) {

                System.out.println("String s have only " + totalOccurrence + " symbol \",\"");

            } else {

                int count = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

                    if (s.charAt(i) == ',') {

                        count++;

                        if (count == n) {

                            String resultString = s.substring(0, i) + s1 + s.substring(i, s.length());

                            System.out.println(resultString);

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }


}

}
```

> Output :

```
1. Enter Nth Occurrence
5
String s have only 3 symbol ","


2. Enter Nth Occurrence
2
17.4755,2.0585,,,,,23.6489,12.0045
```